# How to change jEdit autoclose html tag functionality?

Tags: tags, jedit

jEdit autocloses the last open html tag when typing

I want jEdit to close the open tag automatically (as it closes a bracket) and  places the cursor between the tags.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jEdit does not auto-close any brackets.
I guess you are using the FirstMate plugin or something similar which is providing that functionality.
The functionality you are searching is in the XML plugin which also handles HTML.
In its settings you have an option for autoclosing on typing "

Comment: Hi Vampire.
Yes, I use FirstMate plugin, but it hasn't autoclose tags feature.
As you suggest, I add XML plugin in jEdit. 
I have ticked "Insert closing tag when opening is typed",and it works perfect.
Thanks!